# PHP mysql_query syntax error?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having trouble getting an sql query to go through to the database. I am checking this with an `if ($sql) {echo "success";} else {echo "error";}` and I keep getting "error". The code preceding my query all seems to work. If the query syntax is correct, what could be potential trip-ups that I have overlooked? Here is the code in question:

```
$sql = mysql_query(
    "INSERT INTO monthly_balances (
        bal_id,
        account_id,
        bal_date,

        bal_month_sales,
        bal_month_returns,
        bal_month_net,
        bal_month_coop,

        bal_YTD_sales,
        bal_YTD_returns,
        bal_YTD_net,

        bal_lastYTD_sales,
        bal_lastYTD_returns,
        bal_lastYTD_net
    ) 
    VALUES (
        DEFAULT,
        '$account_id',
        '$bal_date',

        '$bal_month_sales',
        '$bal_month_returns',
        '$bal_month_net',
        '$bal_month_coop',

        '$bal_YTD_sales',
        '$bal_YTD_returns',
        '$bal_YTD_net',

        '$bal_lastYTD_sales',
        '$bal_lastYTD_returns',
        '$bal_lastYTD_net'
    )
 ");


if($sql) {
    echo 'success';
}
else {
    echo 'error';
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Replace `error` with `mysql_error()`

Comment: did you try echoing the error. also please update your code to use mysqli or pdo!

Comment: I have echoed the error. It reads: `Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails   (`coop`.`monthly_balances`, CONSTRAINT `monthly_balances_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`) REFERENCES `entries` (`account_id`))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the **[docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#idm47273258468336)**:

> MySQL rejects any INSERT or UPDATE operation that attempts to create a
> foreign key value in a child table if there is no a matching candidate
> key value in the parent table.

So basically, the value of `account_id` that you are entering in `monthly_balances` is not present in `account_id` of table `entries`.

When a column is declared as foreign key in reference to some column in another table, the foreign column **cannot** contain a value before the parent column has it.

#### Note:

[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: What you are saying makes sense to me, however, I have set the foreign key to `account_id` of table `accounts` in mysql, which exists. So how is this possible?

Comment: @bsapaka From the error it seems to be referring to the `entries` table. You should probably re-check it.

Comment: I did recheck it. Turns out I have dislexia

Thanks for your help.